# Postgresql ldap authentication

Tags: postgresql, azure, ldap

I try to use the ldap authentication method to login to postgres with Azure AD. 
With ldapsearch from the same machine, I get a connection and can use the searchonly user. But as soon as I use postgres I get:

> could not start LDAP TLS session: Can't contact LDAP server

I tried on port 636 and 389. A tcp dump showed me that the connection was made correctly and the search was successful, but it just times out on postgres side.

> psql: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly

Was anyone able to configure postgresql via the ldap authentication against Azure AD?

Using; Debain 9.6, Postgresql 9.6, Azure AD

pg_hba rule:

> host all all 0.0.0.0/0 ldap ldapserver="ldaps1.domain.com" ldapbasedn="dc=domain,dc=com" ldapbinddn="cn=searchonly,ou=local,dc=domain,dc=com" ldapbindpasswd="myPW" ldapsearchattribute="userPrincipalName"

Even more strange, using the simple bind method it is working without problems. Why not with bind + search?